# Print a variable followed by a string in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am writing a MIPS program that asks you for your name and then prints the line Hi , how are you? However my code...

```
#Program that fulfills the requirements of COS250 lab 1
#Nick Gilbert

.data #Section that declares variables for program
firstPromptString:  .asciiz     "What is your name: "
secondPromptString: .asciiz     "Enter width: "
thirdPromptString:  .asciiz     "Enter length: "

name:           .space      20

firstOutStringOne:     .asciiz     "Hi "
firstOutStringTwo:  .asciiz     ", how are you?"
secondOutString:        .asciiz     "The perimeter is ____"
thirdOutString:     .asciiz     "The area is _____"

.text #Section that declares methods for program
main:
    #Printing string asking for a name
        la $a0, firstPromptString #address of the string to print
        li $v0, 4 #Loads system call code for printing a string into $v0 so syscall can execute it
        syscall #call to print the prompt. register $v0 will have what syscall is, $a0-$a3 contain args for syscall if needed

        #Prompting user for response and storing response
        la $a0, name
        li $v0, 8 #System call code for reading a string
        li $a1, 20
        syscall

        #Printing response to name
        la $a0, firstOutStringOne
        li $v0, 4 #System call code for printing a string
        syscall

        la $a0, name
        li $v0, 4 #System call code for printing a string
        syscall

        la $a0, firstOutStringTwo
        li $v0, 4 #System call code for printing a string
        syscall
```

Prints "Hi " and then ", how are you" on separate lines. I need the message to be on a single line

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the `'\n'` (newline) comes from user input.
 After the program prints `"What is your name: "`, the user types his name *and enters it by hitting return*. This places a `'\n'` after the name in the buffer. When the buffer is subsequently printed, the newline is printed with it. To prevent this, the `'\n'` needs to be replaced with `'\0'`, aka the string terminator. So you need a function like `memchr()` or `strchr()` to look for the `'\n'` and replace it.

Comment: Yes. And since you probably don't have access to those ready-made functions, you can program a simple routine that does what you want: For each char in the string, if it is =='0' then goto end; if it is =='\n' then replace it with '0' and goto end; else increment pointer and goto next iteration.